# Tool for transferring data from linux machine to MSSQL on remote (Windows) machine

Tags: linux, sql-server

Is there some kind of opensource / free tools for transferring data from a linux machine to a remote (Windows Server 2012) MSSQL Database Server that can be called / controlled via a bash script? Hoping for something *besides BCP Utility* (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-2017) as have been having very bad problems with that tool presently (mostly to do with very poor error messages being thrown by the program (https://stackoverflow.com/q/51959254/8236733)).

Have access to a Hadoop cluster and HDFS and have been using `sqoop` (http://sqoop.apache.org/) for some data transfers, yet need something much faster when dealing with very large datasets (when working properly, BCP does very well, just does not run without error for ~45% of the datasets I've tried). Ultimately, intending to use this tool as part of an `Apache Airflow` (https://airflow.apache.org/) workflow.

If anyones' had a similar problem and worked around it some other way, please let me know as well. Know very little about databases, remote connection, and windows, so verbose detail or an additional example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [I love lamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gId6nrMDmUU)

Comment: For others finding this post, LAMP is (probably) this: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-a-lamp-stack/. In any case, @Mawg the need to use MSSQL Server is a fixed constraint for my use case (so can't use the MySQL (M) portion of the LAMP stack).

Comment: Lolx! My comment was in regard to your user name :-)